# How do I make an Android app control phone silence even when app isn't running?

Tags: android

Say in the app I want the phone to silence beginning at one time and ending at another. I get how to silence and unsilence the phone, but how can I do this where even if you use the task manager to exit your application, or use a Task Killer, the phone still silences when it should?

Comment: so, have an app that runs even when its not?

Comment: Yes, I have seen this done before on apps that silence your phone at a time you set, even if the app isn't running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for that.. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example) and [this link](http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/) for more info..